# multilanguage support to xml text search php

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file which can be in any language(finnish, italian, swedish, dutch) I have saved the xml using headers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

The saved xml contains special characters and some html codes as

```
&#8271; for single code etc.
```

Now I want to provide a search text functionality using this xml as source as follows

```
$xml->xpath("//page[data[contains(., '".strtoupper($string)."')]]")
```

Where am strggling is that from php when I try to provide the $search_text as variable it's not matching these `&#8271;` and producing error 
for e.g. the word **nell’Esercizio** is there as `nell&#8217;Esercizio` in xml and hence my search result is empty for xpath.

I tried htmlentities and htmlspecialchars but no luck. For special characters i tried utf8_encode(), utf8_decode() combination and it worked (for finnish language) but for these html characters it's failing.

What should be the proper way of searching text in a xml file in diff language via a php application ?

Comment: This might be a duplicate question but I have searched SO and never stumbled to the functionality am looking for. Any reference link would also be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xpath expression has to be UTF-8, the encoding of the document is not relevant. DOM uses UTF-8 and converts on load/save. I think your problem is the `strtoupper()`. You need to use unicode save transliterations.

- [ext/intl](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php)
- [ext/mbstring](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)

Comment: Hi ThW,
I tried the approach you gave unfortunately that didn't worked. My task was to search a text in a iso-8859-1 xml file and the text i was searching is  **nell’esercizio** i tried transliterate approach and also end up trying _iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)_ but in vain.

Comment: You're converting into the wrong direction. The XPath has to be UTF-8 and you have to use UTF-8 string functions.

Comment: hi ThW 
your suggestion did helped, the issue was with strtoupper() removing that piece worked just fine and also that I have to use utf8 with xpath. 
Thanks.